# Angular 16 ProvideMockStore() breaking TestBed after using this.store.selectSignal()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, signals, ngrx, angular16

After upgrading an Angular project to v.16 and refactoring RxJS to start using Signals, I started using the new function `this.store.selectSignal()`.

Does someone else has ever faced the following error?

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changes')
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/core/components/changelog/store/changelog.selectors.ts:20:15)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:793:30)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:673:39)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:696:43)
    at apply (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:796:36)
    at selector (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:673:39)
    at ComputedImpl.computation (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm2022/ngrx-store.mjs:535:31)
    at ComputedImpl.recomputeValue (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:2510:29)
    at ComputedImpl.onProducerUpdateValueVersion (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:2496:14)
    at ComputedImpl.signal (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:2532:14)
```

Here is the test:

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {provideMockStore} from '@ngrx/store/testing';

import {ChangelogComponent} from './changelog.component';
import {ModalComponent} from '../modal/modal/modal.component';

describe('ChangelogComponent', () => {
    let component: ChangelogComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChangelogComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FontAwesomeModule, ModalComponent, ChangelogComponent],
            providers: [provideMockStore()],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChangelogComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The component has a facade:

```
    changes = this.facade.changes;

    constructor(private facade: ChangelogFacade) {}
```

In the facade I'm getting the signal from the selector.
`changes = this.store.selectSignal(getChangelog);`

I expected my tests to run succeffully.
At first, I was using a regular selector with an `Observable` and `| async` in the template.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was initializing the mock store data.

```
providers: [provideMockStore({
  initialState: {
    changelog: {
      changes: [
        {
          tagName: 'v1.0.0',
          date: '2021-01-01',
          changes: ['Initial release'],
        },
      ],
      isLoading: false,
    },
  },
})]
```